# laravel how to show list of items based on first letter from database table field

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

I am new to Laravel technology. In my Laravel project, I want to retrieve the column values of a particular table, and view the values in a list based on the first letter.

Examples:

A

- Andrewson
- Anniejain
- Amaway

B

- Boblique
- bourneiew

From the list above, I want to retrieve the name category on my database table. From the table, I want retrieve the names and show the names in a blade view list.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54kJC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can group the data from the using **laravel** collection grouping, in your case group it using "**category name**" and get the ***first character*** of the key later **uppercase** it.
Example **https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby**